# html5 geolocation theory - what if the GPS is off?

Tags: android, html, gps, geolocation

I've got a website which is going to be used through Android smartphones (Samsung Galaxy S3). The website is picking up the GPS location when the user makes any updates and saves the location (and accuracy). The code for getting the location is below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLocate" Text="Locate GPS" OnClientClick="GetLocation(); return false;" runat="server" Height="0px" Width="0px" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

             function GetLocation()
             {
                 if (navigator.geolocation)
                 {
                     //don't need it to be that accurate, 30 second timeout, 60 second max age
                     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ShowPosition, ShowError, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 60000 });
                 }
                 else { alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser."); }
             }
             function ShowPosition(position)
             {
                 document.getElementById('lblLat').value = position.coords.latitude;
                 document.getElementById('lblLon').value = position.coords.longitude;
                 document.getElementById('lblAcc').value = position.coords.accuracy;
                 document.getElementById('btnUpdate').click();
             }
             function ShowError(error)
             {
                 alert("Could not obtain location - updates will still go ahead");
                 document.getElementById('lblLat').value = "ERROR WHEN LOCATING USER";
                 document.getElementById('lblLon').value = "ERROR WHEN LOCATING USER";
                 document.getElementById('lblAcc').value = "n/a";
                 document.getElementById('btnUpdate').click();
             }
         </script>
```

Now, this is working brilliantly but I've only tried it briefly - got some more testing to do tomorrow. It's not too accurate, but there's a lot of buildings and things the signal may get bounced off around here but that's by the by.

In order to conserve battery (these things have to last a day, if not longer), we'd like to have the GPS function off until needed, at which point it turns on, grabs a location, then turns off. Or at least "ticks over" until it's needed (I realise that a GPS location may not be accurate unless the GPS has been on for a while). So I turned off the GPS and used my page with the code above, and it's still getting coordinates, which is perfect.

As I said, I've still got some testing to do, but does anyone know exactly what's happening in the case of my GPS being off? Is my handset getting coordinates via 3G or some other method, or is it turning on my GPS to grab it (no GPS icon appears)? And if it is doing this, is my GPS being deactivated afterwards to conserve battery?